# Android - best way to persist large arraylist across runtime changes

Tags: android, performance, arraylist

Till now, I was just putting everything, including non-view members, in the bundle in `onSaveInstanceState()` and retrieving it back in `onRestoreInstanceState()`. But I feel like I am not doing it the right way by persisting non-view data this way.

I have 6 arraylists of custom non-view objects in my app and all can grow considerably large. Serializing/deserializing them each time on screen rotation is causing a noticeable delay now. I was wondering if there's another way to do it that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

For configuration changes (e.g. rotation) there is an alternative solution. You can return an object in [`onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29) (or, alternatively, use a Fragment with [`setRetainInstance(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29)).

Unlike `onSaveInstanceState()`, this Object is **not** serialized, but just passed "at is", so there is no performance hit.

The `onSaveInstanceState() / onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` mechanism is mostly intended for restoring the state when the app is killed by the system (e.g. due to low memory) and then restarted. In this case, a higher delay is justified.

Comment: Agreed.  I had to do the same thing when persisting a ton of bitmaps between config changes. Just created a fragment to store the bitmaps and had it retain its instance.